# Take undo tablespace datafile offline ,which is in recovery mode?

Tags: linux, oracle, rhel

I am trying to take undo datafile in offline mode using following command

```
alter database datafile '<datafile path>' offline;
```

this datafile is in recovery mode.  Oracle shows message as database successfully altered.

But after executing this command when I select entries in v$datafile. The file that I just made offline remains in this table.

Can somebody please tell how to take undo datafile  offline.

```
OS: RHEL
Oracle version: 11g
Datafile status: Recovery
```

EDIT:

I already tried command

`alter database datafile '/your/data/file/name' offline drop`

it says database altered successfully ,

```
alter database open;
```

fails with message <my undo log file name> needs recovery of undo file.

I cannot recover it as I have lost the archive files. 
It seems like file is getting dropped logically not physically. Now I just want my database to be up and running and for that I want to take this file to be offline.

When I check v$datafile table it shows the entry for the file irrespective of `alter database datafile '<datafile path>' offline drop;` ran succesfully, Please help me resolve the issue. Database is down from the morning and I could not get it started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?
What are you trying to accomplish?

In v$tablespaces are the tablespaces listed. The datafiles are
in v$datafiles.

A tablespace can have multiple datafiles.
How is your database and backup setup ?
Do you need the tablespace?

If you just want to get rid of the datafile (and the tablespace) you could try to drop it while in mount mode:

```
startup mount
alter database datafile '/your/data/file/name' offline drop;
alter database open;
drop tablespace your_tablespace_name including contents and datafiles;
```

If you do need the tablespace online, you start with restoring the datafile and do a full media recovery.

I hope this works,
Ronald.

Comment: hi ik_zelf: I already tried command 'alter database datafile '/your/data/file/name' offline drop' it says database altered successfully ,'alter database open;' fails with message <my undo log file name> needs recovery. ,, It cannot be recovered as I have lost the archive files. Now I just want my database to be up and running and want to take this file offline.

Comment: I am afraid that you are out of luck. I assume that your undo tablespace needs recovery because you had a problem with your storage. You could try with 'recover database;' and hope that your redofiles are good an enough available. If not, you need to mess with nasty settings like undo_management=manual and _ALLOW_RESETLOGS_CORRUPTION = TRUE
and _CORRUPTED_ROLLBACK_SEGMENTS = (_SYSSMU1$, ....) You will make the list while reading the alertlog after restarts. This is no fun. Could be better to just start over.